# Import web sql contents into SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, mobile, web-sql

I'm creating an app for mobile and web and I'm using Visual Studio and SQL Server. I'm creating a mobile app that will create a web sql database but the web app is using SQL Server. Can I use SQL Server for the mobile app or is there a solution that connects the web sql database to the SQL Server database?

Comment: You need more details here. Yes, its possible through various coding like php or C#, depends on what you are dong there. But the best way is to backup, convert and then import into SQL. You can do this through a VS SSIS package.